# How can I determine which detail page tab I'm on in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have placed an LWC component on the Task object record page. Now the requirement is I want to add that lwc component on the detail tab as well as on related tab but some part is not visible on the related tab.

Comment: Just add an `@api` property and related target property to control the LWC's presentation/behaviour, and have the admin/page creator set this value appropriately.

Comment: @PhilW thanks, that works

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to detect the tab, but then this isn't required. Instead update your LWC to introduce an `@api` property with related target property and use this in the LWC's presentation/behaviour to produce the required visual options.

All you then require is for the admin/page author to set this value appropriately on the usages of your LWC in the details and related tabs.